# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

I am new with angularJS, got an old project, 
The error is in the jquery.js file, every place when using "config" not compile, why?

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Lisa due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: config
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/unpr?p0=config
    at http://localhost:5510/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:20
    at http://localhost:5510/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4264:23
    at getService (http://localhost:5510/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4415:64)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:5510/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4445:84)
    at runInvokeQueue (http://localhost:5510/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4365:49)
    at http://localhost:5510/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4374:25
    at forEach (http://localhost:5510/bower_components/angular/angular.js:337:34)
```

any solution will be welcom

Comment: What version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: Good place to start @tbone849, for sure. This is a dependency injection issue, it's probably not that "config" being referenced in the code posted but somewhere where "config" is injected. Unknown provider errors are difficult to track down, especially when unfamiliar with the project. Is there an angularjs service in the project called config somewhere in there like .factory('config', configFn)?

Comment: Does it work with none minified files?

Comment: @JamesIngold  thanks, no

Comment: @felixmosh no, I have regular files. just want it to run :)